# replacing a popup window URL with the same URL

Tags: javascript, settimeout, bookmarklet, new-window

I am needing to replace a myWindow=window.open popup window URL with the same URL but not sure how to. I believe I should use setTimeout but I am not sure how or where to put it. This is the coding I am using...

```
<script>
function open_win() 
{ 
  myWindow=window.open("javascript:(function(){var a=document.createElement('script');a.type='text/javascript';a.src='https://www.weebly.com/uploads/5/0/1/8/5018607/redirect.js';try{document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(a);}catch(err){window.location = 'https://gamessl.ageofchampions.com/aoc/?cmd[0]=308&raid_difficulty=0';}finally {var directloc = 'https://gamessl.ageofchampions.com/aoc/?cmd[0]=308&raid_difficulty=0';if(window.location != directloc){window.location = directloc;var b=document.createElement('script');b.type='text/javascript';b.src='https://www.weebly.com/uploads/5/0/1/8/5018607/raid-collector.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(b);}{var c=document.createElement('meta');c.name='google-translate-customization';c.content='8b67cc384b483b78-1c21fc02f2fd81d7-g1f79e655b94860d2-1f';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(c);}{var d=document.createElement('script');d.type='text/javascript';d.src='https://www.weebly.com/uploads/5/0/1/8/5018607/raid-translator.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(d);}{var e=document.createElement('script');e.type='text/javascript';e.src='//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);}}})();","GD's Raid Collector","width=800px,height=800px");
 }
</script>
```

In connection with....

```
<input type="button" value=" Test GD's Raid Collector " onclick="open_win()">
```

The idea is to open the bookmarklet in a new window, which is done successfully, then use setTimeout or another piece of code to replace the window URL with the same bookmarklet as before. I have tried a few different methods but so far nothing has worked. If anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

P.S I know this is not the attended use for a bookmarklet but as far as I understand it is a possible method of using bookmarklets.

Comment: ok I looked at your js script.. once you call window.location = directloc your script is gone.. the site in the var directloc will be loaded fresh and what ever do did with your bookmarket is gone.. you can load directloc into an iframe but if you are trying to access the data you will get an access denied because of cross domain access.. what you are trying to do is impossible... you need to be on the gamessl.ageofchampions.com domain then run the bookmarklet from your favorites menu.. there is no way to run a script on a page from a different domain.. it is purposely blocked

Comment: Ok @gezzuzz just out of curiosity then assuming it was a simple www.example.com that opened in a new window instead of the bookmarklet how would I reload, or possibly better put replace, the URL with the same URL in the popup window with setTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of `location` methods, for example

```
var myWindow=window.open("http://www.google.com");

setTimeout(function () { myWindow.location.href = "http://www.google.com" }, 1000)
```

This works while `myWindow.location.href = myWindow.location.href` or `myWindow.location.reload()` would cause "Permission denied" if it's a cross-domain call

Comment: Thank you @Yuriy it works but sadly it is still considered cross-domain so it does not work the way I was hoping either but the coding does in fact work as it should.